# Javascript aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help in javascript. I need to remove the object which already in the path.

As you can see there are 3 paths property.

1) golang
2) Root/DCL/JAVA
3) Root/DCL/JAVA/JAVA1/JAVA2

point 2 JAVA is the root of JAVA 2 folder. I need to remove the whole object from the array.

**the object can be in any position.**

```
[
  {
    level: '0',
    paths: 'golang',
    name: 'golang',
    updatedOn: 1998902546,
    type: 'folder',
    uuid: 'cd315c90-a9f8-48d9-9aed-a97b246b27e9',
    createdOn: 1998902546,
    elementType: 'folder'
  },
  {
    level: '4', //. remove this object in an array because Root/BCL/JAVA/JAVA1/JAVA2 (JAVA2)is a child of JAVA -> Root/BCL/JAVA
    paths: 'Root/BCL/JAVA/JAVA1/JAVA2',
    name: 'JAVA2',
    type: 'folder',
    elementType: 'folder',
    uuid: 'fe32e4b8-37be-4416-b129-852da83f5549',
    createdOn: 2113950571
  },
  { 
    level: '2', 
    paths: 'Root/BCL/JAVA',
    name: 'JAVA',
    updatedOn: 2039112906,
    type: 'folder',
    elementType: 'folder',
    uuid: 'cd315c90-a9f8-48d9-9aed-a97b246b27e7',
    creadedOn: 2039112906
  }
]
```

```
// split the paths by "/" and pushed in another array to match
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        const l = parseInt(list[i].level, 10)
        let splitArr = [];
        if (list[i].paths.length > 0) {
          splitArr = list[i].paths.split('/');
          arr2.push(splitArr)
        } else {
          arr2.push(list[i].paths)
        }

      }
```

not sure split is required. a bit lost now, please guide.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: so you just want to strip the last node right? `path.replace(/\/[^/]+$/,'')`

Comment: added more description. hope you will get the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filters on if it can find the string at position 0 of any other path.
You didn't specify what happens if paths are the same, but this will only keep the first one.

```js
data = [
 {
    level: '0',
    paths: 'golang',
    name: 'golang',
    updatedOn: 1998902546,
    type: 'folder',
    uuid: 'cd315c90-a9f8-48d9-9aed-a97b246b27e9',
    createdOn: 1998902546,
    elementType: 'folder'
  },
  {
    level: '2',
    paths: 'Root/BCL/JAVA',
    name: 'JAVA',
    updatedOn: 2039112906,
    type: 'folder',
    elementType: 'folder',
    uuid: 'cd315c90-a9f8-48d9-9aed-a97b246b27e7',
    createdOn: 2039112906
  },
  {
    level: '4',
    paths: 'Root/BCL/JAVA/JAVA1/JAVA2',
    name: 'JAVA2',
    type: 'folder',
    elementType: 'folder',
    uuid: 'fe32e4b8-37be-4416-b129-852da83f5549',
    createdOn: 2113950571
  },
  {
    level: '2',
    paths: 'Root/BCL/JAVA',
    name: 'JAVA',
    updatedOn: 2039112906,
    type: 'folder',
    elementType: 'folder',
    uuid: 'cd315c90-a9f8-48d9-9aed-a97b246b27e7',
    createdOn: 2039112906
  },
  {
    level: '4',
    paths: 'Root/BCL/JAVA/JAVA1/JAVA2',
    name: 'JAVA2',
    type: 'folder',
    elementType: 'folder',
    uuid: 'x',
    createdOn: 2113950571
  },
  {
    level: '2',
    paths: 'Root/BCL/JAVA',
    name: 'JAVA',
    updatedOn: 2039112906,
    type: 'folder',
    elementType: 'folder',
    uuid: 'cd315c90-a9f8-48d9-9aed-a97b246b27e7',
    createdOn: 2039112906
  }
]
console.log(
data.filter((p,i)=>data.every((x,j)=>x===p||!p.paths.startsWith(x.paths)||(x.paths===p.paths&&i>j)))
)
```

Comment: each user will have there own file structure. they can share folder/file with a group/user. I am getting all the folder which group can access. user can share the root dir and sub dir. i just wanted to find the root of the folder. if it's shared then remove the subfolder. I am wanted to achieve this via neo4j query. but don't know how to write it. that's trying this way

Comment: oh, so there won't be dupes I guess?  Does this behave the way you want?

Comment: I think so. will try to modify the graph and test it out again. thanks, mate really appreciate

Comment: sorry it was other way around .. need to remove object Root/BCL/JAVA/JAVA1/JAVA2

Comment: Just have to swap the startsWith around.

Comment: could you please explain what you did ... need to understand thx

Comment: `.filter` excludes when return false.  `.every` checks that every iteration returns true.  so if x===p (same object) return true, if no other path startsWith this path return true, if equal paths and first occurrence